# How do I set the default reason for a new state in a customized process?

Tags: azure-devops

I've created an inherited process in Microsoft Team Services, based on the Agile process. I've added a new state "Wont fix" to the Bug work item type.

[image]

When I set a bug to "Wont fix", the Reason field defaults to "Moved to state Wont fix". Although it is editable, I would like it to default to "Negligible impact". Ideally, I'd like to also provide a drop-down list of other reasons.

Can I do this via the web interface? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do this via web interface.

Based on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/18/vsts-process-customization-futures-june-2016/) article, REST API support for customization will be available.